# Does AutoMapper pattern violate principle of DDD?

Tags: domain-driven-design, automapper, abp

I am trying Abp framework recently and happily found that it is a wonderful implementation of DDD. But since it uses AutoMapper to translate DTOs into Entities/Aggregates, I have noticed it's able to short-circuit my private setters of Aggregates, which obviously violated the main rule of DDD. Although the goal of AutoMapper is to reduce manual operations, but DDD emphasizes invariant through private setters.

How can I make there two seemingly conflicting concept clear and use this framework smoothly? Does that mean I have to give up AutoMapper to keep DDD principles or vice versa?

I believe AutoMapper is not an anti-pattern of DDD since it's very popular in the community. In another word, if AutoMapper can use reflection (as I know) to set private setters, anybody else can. Does that means private setters is essentially unsafe?

Thanks for anyone could help me or have me a hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) is: *A convention-based object-object mapper in .NET.*

In itself, AutoMapper does not violate the principle of DDD. It is how you use it that possibly does.

> How can I make there two seemingly conflicting concept clear and use this framework smoothly? Does that mean I have to give up AutoMapper to keep DDD principles or vice versa?

No, you don't have to give up AutoMapper.
You can specify `.IgnoreAllPropertiesWithAnInaccessibleSetter` for each map.

Related: [How to configure AutoMapper to globally Ignore all Properties With Inaccessible Setter(private or protected)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39752335/8601760)

> In another word, if AutoMapper can use reflection (as I know) to set private setters, anybody else can. Does that means private setters is essentially unsafe?

No, that means that reflection is very powerful.

Comment: Thank you, I have got that, No pattern is silver bullet.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know a lot about the Abp framework.  Private setters is just good old traditional OOP which is used in DDD (encapsulation). You should expose public methods from your aggregate that will change its state. Automapper can be used in your application layer where you map the DTOs to domain building blocks (like value objects) and you pass them as parameters in your aggregate public functions that will change its own state and enforce invariants. Having said that not everyone loves Automapper :)

Comment: The thing is, if the mechanism of reflection can modify properties with private setters, anyone who uses my modules can invade my Aggregates (intentionally or by unintentionally), is that truth?

Comment: @SillyJumper, yes but that is by design. Reflection needs to be that powerful to be able to implement some complex use cases. The good thing is that you control your dependencies. If you find that you don't like `AutoMapper` because it messes with your objects, you can stop using it.

Comment: Like @nova said, you can use `AutoMapper` to map only simple objects that have no invariants of their own, like most value objects. You could map the rest by hand (ie. call a constructor or factory method with arguments taken from the DTO properties). Better yet, you can take this logic and place it into a factory method on the Aggregate Root, which takes the DTO as input and whatever else is needed, and you use that factory method in your application services to create a valid AR instance, then persist it or whatever your use case is doing.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make there two seemingly conflicting concept clear and use this framework smoothly?

By configuring AutoMapper's profile to construct the aggregate root using a custom expression that uses the aggregate's factory methods or constructors. Here is an example from one of my projects:

```csharp
public class BphNomenclatureManagerApplicationAutoMapperProfile : Profile
{
    public BphNomenclatureManagerApplicationAutoMapperProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<BphCompany, BphCompanyDto>(MemberList.Destination);
        CreateMap<CreateUpdateBphCompanyDto, BphCompany>(MemberList.Destination)
            // invariants preserved by use of AR constructor:
            .ConstructUsing(dto => new BphCompany(
                dto.Id,
                dto.BphId,
                dto.Name,
                dto.VatIdNumber,
                dto.TradeRegisterNumber,
                dto.IsProducer
            ));
    }
}
```